# how to make an object orbiting respect to x axis in opengl

Tags: graphics, 3d, transform

Suppose I've created a cube and I want it to orbit around the x-axis after dragging it off the x-axis.

What matrix operations do I need to perform?
I know that for rotation respect to x axis, I need to do the following operation

[image]

but what about orbiting? By orbiting I mean the cube will move around x-axis as a circle without self-rotation.

Thanks.

Comment: Which X axis? The X axis in what coordinate system?

Comment: @NicolBolas the x axis in world coordinate system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An orbit movement is actually just a translation. You have two options: Either combine the rotation matrix with a translation and revert the rotation, or calculate an appropriate translation vector.

The first option would be:

```
R(theta) * T(0, 0, orbitRadius) * R(-theta)
```

The second option would be:

```
T(0, -orbitRadius * sin(theta), orbitRadius * cos(theta))
```

Comment: Thank you Nico, for the answer. However I do have one more question. For example, if I drag the cursor from left to right then theta will be (xbegin - xend), then how do I reverse the orbit movement on the same track by dragging cursor from right to left?

Comment: You can do the same thing on the way back: `theta = thetaOld + (xbegin - xend)`. Since `(xbegin - xend)` will have the opposite sign, it will rotate in the opposite direction.